# axios request, reading validation message from error object

Tags: reactjs, axios

send an axios put request and getting status code 400 error.

Server sends a user friendly validation eror message
it looks like in dev tools:
[image]

in catch block I expect to get the message with error.message but this equals to  `Request failed with status code 400`

```
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: SETTINGS_ALERT,
    })
    const response = await axios.put(
      `/author/me`,
      {
        data: {
          DisplayName: displayName,
          Description: description,
        },
      }
    )
    dispatch({
      type: SETTINGS_UPDATE_PROFILE_SUCCESS,
      payload: response.data,
    })
  } catch (error) {
//need to handle it here, bu error.message not works
    dispatch({
      type: SETTINGS_LOAD_FAIL,
      error: error.message,
    })
  }
```

How can I read this message properly??

Comment: try using `console.log(String(error)` first. See what comes up.

Comment: I think that error.response.data is what you are looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The detailed message you want is in `error.response.data`:

```
dispatch({
      type: SETTINGS_LOAD_FAIL,
      error: error.response.data,
    })
```